# How to read command-line output of cygwin program in real-time in Delphi?

Tags: linux, windows, delphi, cygwin, console-application

I need to read lengthy command-line output of originally Linux-based Cygwin program. It works great under `cmd.exe`, printing new line every few seconds.

When I use this code below, which was discussed many times here on SO, `ReadFile` function does not return until that program stops. Then all output is provided by `ReadFile` and printed.

How to make that output read by `ReadFile` as soon as it is available?

MSDN says that `ReadFile` doesn't return until `CR` is reached in `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` mode, or buffer full. That progam uses Linux line breaks `LF`, not Windows `CRLF`. I used small buffer 32 bytes and disabled `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` (*By the way what's the right way of disabling it?*).

Maybe `ReadFile` doesn't return because of some other issue with Cygwin program itself, not just `LF` line breaks? But it works fine in Windows `cmd.exe`, why not in Delphi console application?

```
const
  CommandExe:string = 'iperf3.exe ';
  CommandLine:string = '-c 192.168.1.11 -u -b 1m -t 8 -p 5001 -l 8k -f m -i 2';
  WorkDir:string = 'D:\PAS\iperf3\win32';// no trailing \
var
  SA: TSecurityAttributes;
  SI: TStartupInfo;
  PI: TProcessInformation;
  StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite: THandle;
  WasOK,CreateOk: Boolean;
  Buffer: array[0..255] of AnsiChar;//  31 is Ok
  BytesRead: Cardinal;
  Line:ansistring;

  try// except
  with SA do begin
    nLength := SizeOf(SA);
    bInheritHandle := True;
    lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
  end;
  CreatePipe(StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite, @SA, 0);
  try
    with SI do
    begin
      FillChar(SI, SizeOf(SI), 0);
      cb := SizeOf(SI);
      dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
      wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
      hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); // don't redirect stdin
      hStdOutput := StdOutPipeWrite;
      hStdError := StdOutPipeWrite;
    end;
    Writeln(WorkDir+'\'+CommandExe+' ' + CommandLine);
    CreateOk := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(WideString(WorkDir+'\'+CommandExe+' ' + CommandLine)),
                              @SA, @SA, True,// nil, nil,
                              CREATE_SUSPENDED or CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS or CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,// 0,
                              nil,
                              PChar(WideString(WorkDir)), SI, PI);
    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeWrite);// must be closed here otherwise ReadLn further doesn't work
    ResumeThread(PI.hThread);
    if CreateOk then
      try// finally
        repeat
          WasOK := ReadFile(StdOutPipeRead, Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BytesRead, nil);
          if BytesRead > 0 then
          begin
            Buffer[BytesRead] := #0;
            Line := Line + Buffer;
            Writeln(Line);
          end;
        until not WasOK or (BytesRead = 0);
        ReadLn;
        WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess, INFINITE);
      finally
        CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
        CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
      end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeRead);
  end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln('Exception '+E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
```

Also: why do we have to close this handle right after CreateProcess? It is used to read program output:

```
CloseHandle(StdOutPipeWrite);
```

If I close it at the end of program, program output is Ok, but ReadLn is never read to stop the program.

HOW TO test all this:
In one command window you start iperf3 server and let it listen:

```
D:\PAS\iperf3\win32>iperf3.exe -s -i 2 -p 5001
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5001
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

In another command window you start the client, which immediately connects to server and start printing output every 2 sec:

```
D:\PAS\iperf3\win32>iperf3.exe -c 192.168.1.11 -u -b 1m -t 8 -p 5001 -l 8k -f m -i 2
Connecting to host 192.168.1.11, port 5001
[  4] local 192.168.1.11 port 52000 connected to 192.168.1.11 port 5001
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-2.00   sec   240 KBytes  0.98 Mbits/sec  30
[  4]   2.00-4.00   sec   240 KBytes  0.98 Mbits/sec  30
[  4]   4.00-6.00   sec   248 KBytes  1.02 Mbits/sec  31
[  4]   6.00-8.00   sec   240 KBytes  0.98 Mbits/sec  30
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-8.00   sec   968 KBytes  0.99 Mbits/sec  0.074 ms  0/121 (0%)
[  4] Sent 121 datagrams
iperf Done.
```

Server prints output as well, together with client:

```
Accepted connection from 192.168.1.11, port 36719
[  5] local 192.168.1.11 port 5001 connected to 192.168.1.11 port 52000
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  5]   0.00-2.00   sec   240 KBytes   983 Kbits/sec  0.052 ms  0/30 (0%)
[  5]   2.00-4.00   sec   240 KBytes   983 Kbits/sec  0.072 ms  0/30 (0%)
[  5]   4.00-6.00   sec   248 KBytes  1.02 Mbits/sec  0.077 ms  0/31 (0%)
[  5]   6.00-8.00   sec   240 KBytes   983 Kbits/sec  0.074 ms  0/30 (0%)
[  5]   8.00-8.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.074 ms  0/0 (nan%)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  5]   0.00-8.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.074 ms  0/121 (0%)
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5001
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

So iperf3 client works great in the command window. Now let's start "my" code in client mode, while iperf3 server is still listening. Server accepts the connection and start printing output

```
Accepted connection from 192.168.1.11, port 36879
[  5] local 192.168.1.11 port 5001 connected to 192.168.1.11 port 53069
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  5]   0.00-2.00   sec   240 KBytes   983 Kbits/sec  0.033 ms  0/30 (0%)
[  5]   2.00-4.00   sec   240 KBytes   983 Kbits/sec  0.125 ms  0/30 (0%)
[  5]   4.00-6.00   sec   248 KBytes  1.02 Mbits/sec  0.106 ms  0/31 (0%)
[  5]   6.00-8.00   sec   240 KBytes   983 Kbits/sec  0.109 ms  0/30 (0%)
[  5]   8.00-8.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.109 ms  0/0 (nan%)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  5]   0.00-8.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.109 ms  0/121 (0%)
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5001
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

it means iperf3 client is started inside of 'my' code, but it is not printing anything! Only after client finished, 'my' code prints this output:

```
Connecting to host 192.168.1.11, port 5001
[  4] local 192.168.1.11 port 53069 connected to 192.168.1.11 port 5001
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-2.00   sec   240 KBytes  0.98 Mbits/sec  30
[  4]   2.00-4.00   sec   240 KBytes  0.98 Mbits/sec  30
[  4]   4.00-6.00   sec   248 KBytes  1.02 Mbits/sec  31
[  4]   6.00-8.00   sec   240 KBytes  0.98 Mbits/sec  30
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-8.00   sec   968 KBytes  0.99 Mbits/sec  0.109 ms  0/121 (0%)
[  4] Sent 121 datagrams
iperf Done.
```

So, cygwin program output behaves differently, depending if it runs inside command window or Delphi console application. 
And yes, my output handling code with 'Line' is not perfect, but let's find out how to make ReadFile return in real-time, I'll fix the rest.

Comment: This is one of those things that happens when you paste code found elsewhere

Comment: What is the Cygwin process?

Comment: Sometimes, programs check what kind of output they're connected to. When they're attached to a console, they flush their output frequently (like every line). When they detect they're attached to something else, like a pipe or a disk file, they buffer their output (since it appears that no human can see it anyway). Perhaps the program offers an option to override the default behavior.

Comment: I added definitions on top of code. Cygwin program is iperf3.exe. Please don't advise me to recompile it, I can do that. I believe the problem is more generic, and want to find it for everyone benefit. David Hefferman: I read virtually every posting on SO about pipes and CreateProcess, including your comments, and tried 4 solutions, before posting here.
@quasoft: Zarco Gajic solution provides output only after child program stops, UweRaabe solution from DelphiDabbler is the one I'm asking about here, Kenny solution is almost the same.
I'll provide more info on iperf3.exe below.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: how to cheat to cygwin program so it will believe it is connected to the console?
I added more information in the original question.

Comment: There are some suggestions how to disable pipe buffering in this thread: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe Check if you have any of the suggested tools for unbuffering in your environment

Comment: Also look at this patch for iperf: https://github.com/esnet/iperf/pull/272 This patch made --logfile option of iperf update on each interval. All the patch does is to call the `iflush(test);` function. You need similar behaviour, but for pipes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to make that output read by ReadFile as soon as it is available?

The problem is not in the code you provided. It is already reading output in realtime *(Although there is another problem with the code that is not related, see below)*.

You can try it with the following batch file instead of Cygwin executable:

**test.bat:**

```
timeout 5
echo "1"
timeout 5
echo "2"
timeout 5
echo "3"
```

and the following bash shell file:

**test.sh:**

```
sleep 5
echo "1"
sleep 5
echo "2"
sleep 5
echo "3"
```

It works in realtime and outputs text to console as soon as it is available.

So if the problem is not in the Delphi code, it is related to the Cygwin program.
We need more information about your Cygwin program to help you further.

> MSDN says that ReadFile doesn't return until CR is reached in ENABLE_LINE_INPUT mode, or buffer full.
>   That progam uses linux line breaks LF, not Windows CR LF.
>   I used small buffer 32 bytes, disabled ENABLE_LINE_INPUT - btw what's the right way of disabling it?

You don't need to disable it.

If you've set the buffer to 32 bytes, then as soon as the buffer is full, `ReadFile` function should return those 32 bytes, even with UNIX line endings.

> Maybe ReadFile doesn't return because of some other issue with cygwin program itself, not just LF line breaks?

This is what I suppose. I don't want to guess the possible reasons, but they are not related to difference of line endings.

Yes, non-Windows line endings can make the command wait for a whole buffer to be filled, but cannot cause the ReadFile to block.

> But it works fine in Windows cmd.exe, why not in Delphi console application?

Good question, this is strange. On my side it works both in Delphi and cmd.
That is why I suppose the problem is related to Cygwin application.

> Also: why do we have to close this handle right after CreateProcess?
>       CloseHandle(StdOutPipeWrite);

This is the writing end of the pipe. We don't need the write handle, because we are not writing to the pipe, we are only reading from it.
Your Cygwin application is indirectly writing to that pipe.

---

Also, there are two problems in the code that have to be noted:

- You have a `Line` variable that is of type string and is not initialized.
  Initialize that to empty string (`Line := ''`) at the beginning of the routine/program.
- As you have UNIX line ending in `Buffer`, `ReadFile` will not return unless the buffer is full, thus containing multiple lines.
  You need to either change the call to `WriteLn` routine to `Write` and ignore line endings, or use a parser that separates the lines.
- `Line` variable should either be cleared after being written to `stdout` or should directly receive the value of Buffer, like that:

  ```
  ...
  Buffer[BytesRead] := #0;
  Line := Buffer; // <- Assign directly to Line, do not concatenate

  // TODO: Use a parser to separate the multiple lines
  //       in `Line` and output then with `WriteLn` or
  //       ignore line endings altogether and just use `Write`

  Write(Line);
  ...
  ```

  Unless you do that the size of `Line` will increase progressively until it contains the whole output,
  duplicating.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the C runtime buffer in the Cygwin program, which is outside of the OPs control.  As far as I know nobody has ever come up with a good solution for the case where the child is a Windows program, but Cygwin might be different.  The line endings are irrelevant, by the way; ENABLE_LINE_INPUT only works for consoles, not pipes.

Comment: @Harry Johnston thanks for ENABLE_LINE_INPUT and line endings. Still overall picture is not clear: when I run cygwin program in a command window that is considered in Console. When I run it in Delphi Console application, it communicates via pipes.. is that the reason? What if I run it in Delphi as "cmd.exe /c iperf3.exe . ."? - I did, the same result, all output is at the end.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Agreed, confirmed also in this issue https://github.com/esnet/iperf/issues/299 with similar problem.

Comment: @K-man It seems a good solution is to modify `iperf` and force it to flush every line. Similar to what has been done in this issue https://github.com/esnet/iperf/pull/272

Comment: @quasoft sorry I didn't get this about 'CloseHandle(StdOutPipeWrite)' - 'We don't need the write handle, because we are not writing to the pipe, we are only reading from it. Your Cygwin application is indirectly writing to that pipe.' That handle is attached to SI.hStdOutput and SI.hStdError, that's how cygwin app provides its output, what does it mean 'indirectly'?

Comment: @K-man Consider it bad wording on my side. Also, here is a modified version of iperf with added option to force flushing on every interval: https://github.com/quasoft/iperf/tree/force-flush . But you need to compile and test it.

Comment: @quasoft yes, reading all references, it looks like the problem is on the cygwin program side. I can recompile this one, but.. in my engineering carrier it was always nice to have the simple tool to easy re-format output data to what I needed. CreateProcess usually worked for me, until I got this case. I don't want to create custom-made copies. Why we can't cheat to that program, so it will believe it is running in a Console, and redirect output of that Console to wherever we need to?

Comment: @K-man I agree, but according to all references, it seems to be hard to do that in Windows. Other tools (like git, grep) seem to be flushing output properly (try grep instead of iperf). This problem affects only some utilities.

Comment: Windows does not provide any way to make a pipe that pretends to be a console.  As for the write handle, if you keep your copy of the handle open, it makes it harder to tell when the child process has exited.  (When the last handle to the write end of the pipe is closed, any read operation that is waiting will exit.  But if you've kept your copy of the handle open, that won't happen.)

Comment: @Harry Johnston If there is no smart way, what about some stupid way to launch real Windows Console with, say ShellExecute, which will be real not fake console for cygwin program? Then redirect its output.

Comment: Typically, the program won't be asking "do I have a console" to decide how to do buffering, but rather "is the standard output a console".  So if you redirect the output, it won't work.  What you *can* do is let it output to a real console and read the content (look up the ReadConsoleOutput function).  The downside is (a) it's pretty awkward and (b) there's no way to ensure that none of the output scrolls off the window before you get to see it ... although in this case (b) might not be a problem if you know the output will be slow enough.

Comment: @Harry Johnston you guys are way too smart for this simple problem, but thanks to talking to you, I recognize that if I do
       hStdOutput := GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
      hStdError := GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
the cygwin program starts printing not into pipe, but console, which one - obviously the parent one, because I didn't AllocConsole() - and it works!! at 4:00am here. Both client and server are printing output. Now I have to capture those lines from the Console, which sounds easier to me, especially with your advises.

Comment: ReadConsoleOutputCharacter may be even easier to use since I don't need colors. 'awkward' is the engineering way to go...

Comment: @K-man Good work. Make sure to post an answer with your solution. It might help someone writing a similar console application. You could summarize finding in comments there.

Comment: Sure I will. Actual answer is shared by quasoft and Harry Johnston, I have to figure out how to mark this.

Comment: I couldn't be bothered putting the effort in to post an actual answer, so by all means accept this one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

this is a Summary of solution, thanks to experts who advised here:

Many unix-born programs, which can be launched in Windows with Cygwin package, watch the destination of their output. If stdOut is to a console, output is EOL-buffered. It means that as soon as new line is ready, it is printed, no matter how it is separated: CR or CR+LF. If stdOut is to a pipe or file or something else, output is EOF-buffered, because human is not watching the screen. It means that all multiple lines are printed when program finished (unless we use 'flush', but presumably we don't have the source code). In this case we loose all real-time information.

It's easy to check with this code (with definitions from the very top), put it in right after CreateProcess:

```
    case GetFileType(SI.hStdInput) of
     FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN:Lines.Add('Input Unknown') ;
     FILE_TYPE_DISK:Lines.Add('Input from a File') ;
     FILE_TYPE_CHAR:Lines.Add('Input from a Console') ;
     FILE_TYPE_PIPE:Lines.Add('Input from a Pipe') ;
    end;
    case GetFileType(SI.hStdOutput) of
     FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN:Lines.Add('Output Unknown') ;
     FILE_TYPE_DISK:Lines.Add('Output to a File') ;
     FILE_TYPE_CHAR:Lines.Add('Output to a Console') ;
     FILE_TYPE_PIPE:Lines.Add('Output to a Pipe') ;
   end;
```

If you set your console I/O like this:

```
  hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  hStdOutput := GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  hStdError := GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```

output will be to the console. If you set it like this:

```
  hStdInput :=GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  hStdOutput:=StdOutPipeWrite;
  hStdError :=StdOutPipeWrite;
```

output will be to the pipe. Don't forget to close this end:

```
 CloseHandle(StdOutPipeWrite);
```

for reasons, explained by experts above, it works great. Without it the program can't exit.

I prefer to customize the console a bit, to know exact size:

```
  Rect: TSmallRect;
  Coord: TCoord;
  Rect.Left:=0; Rect.Top:=0; Rect.Right:=80; Rect.Bottom:=30;
  Coord.X:=Rect.Right+1-Rect.Left; Coord.Y:=Rect.Bottom+1-Rect.Top;
  SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),Coord);
  SetConsoleWindowInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),True,Rect);
//  SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),FOREGROUND_RED OR BACKGROUND_BLUE);// for maniacs
```

If it is not a Console application but GUI, the console can be created by

```
AllocConsole();
SetConsoleTitle('Console TITLE');
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(),SW_SHOW);// or SW_HIDE - it will blink
```

Still, back to the main problem: how to read the real-time output of the third-party program? If you are lucky, and that program prints out to the attached pipe line by line, as soon as they are ready, you just read them as above with

```
ReadOk := ReadFile(StdOutPipeRead, Buffer, BufferSize, BytesRead, nil);
```

If program doesn't cooperate, but waits to the very end to fill up the pipe, you have no choice, but to leave it with the console output, as per above. This way program believes that somebody is watching its output (and you really may watch it with SW_SHOW), and prints line by line. Hopefully not very fast, at least 1 line per second. Because you are not just enjoying output, but quickly grabbing those lines from the console, one by one using this quite boring technique..

You may clear console first, before starting program, if you already  worked on it, although it's not necessary for the new console:

```
 Hcwnd:=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
 Coord.X:=0; Coord.Y:=0;
 CharsWritten:=0;
 ClearChar:=#0;
 GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(Hcwnd,BufInfo);
 ConScreenBufSize := BufInfo.dwSize.X * BufInfo.dwSize.Y;// size of the console screen buffer
 FillConsoleOutputCharacter(Hcwnd,           // Handle to console screen buffer
                            Char(ClearChar), // Character to write to the buffer
                            ConScreenBufSize,// Number of cells to write
                            Coord,           // Coordinates of first cell
                            CharsWritten);   // Receive number of characters written
 ResumeThread(PI.hThread);// if it was started with CREATE_SUSPENDED
```

Apparently this works:

```
   BufInfo: _CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO;
   LineBuf,Line:string;
   SetLength(LineBuf, BufInfo.dwMaximumWindowSize.X);// one horizontal line
   iX:=0; iY:=0;
   repeat
    Coord.X:=0; Coord.Y:=iY;
    ReadOk:=ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(Hcwnd,PChar(LineBuf),BufInfo.dwMaximumWindowSize.X,Coord,CharsRead);
    if ReadOk then begin// ReadOk
       if CharsRead > 0 then Line:=Trim(Copy(LineBuf,1,CharsRead)); else Line:='';
```

and you are getting into horrible programming of repeated reading of the same line, until it is not blank, checking the next line(s) as well in case that program does WriteLn(''). If those few lines are blank, check

```
if WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess,10) <> WAIT_TIMEOUT then QuitReading:=true;
```

in case program finished in the middle of console. If output got to the bottom of the console, you repeatedly read that line. If it is the same, check WaitForSingleObject. If it is not, even worse - you have to go back few lines up  to find your previous line, to ensure that program didn't spit few lines too quickly so you missed them. Programs love to do that before finish.

There is a lot of messy code inside this skeleton, especially for such a lousy programmer like me:

```
    if iY < (BufInfo.dwMaximumWindowSize.Y-1-1) then begin// not last line
       if (length(Line)>0) then begin// not blank
                                . . .
                                end// not blank
                           else begin// blank
                                . . .
                                end;// blank
                                                     end// not last line
                                                else begin// last line
       if (length(Line)>0) then begin// not blank
                                . . .
                                end// not blank
                           else begin// blank
                                . . .
                                end;// blank
                                                     end;// last line
    Sleep(200);
   until QuitReading;
```

But it works! It is amazingly printing to the console the real-time data (if you didn't SW_HIDE it), and at the same time your GUI program prints the same lines grabbed from the console and processes them the way you want. When external program finishes, console disappears, and GUI program holds full results.

Comment: Minor nitpick: if the output is to a console, it is unbuffered, not EOL-buffered.  Windows never does EOL buffering.  (But it is fairly common for programs to write an entire line in a single call anyway, in which case the distinction is irrelevant.)